# SSRS passing parameter in between values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I got some SSRS question. I need to pass in between values in parameters. How can I do it? Sample data:

| No. Records | Student Name |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | Anne |
| 5 | Rick |
| 4 | John |
| 3 | Nick |
| 2 | Hazel |
| 2 | Rica |
| 1 | Mitch |

The SSRS parameter should show something like this:

Select No. of Records:

1-2

3-4

5 or more

Boolean value is not working on this case

Comment: Can you post the report dataset SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, this is probably the simplest if it's not something you will repeat often.

Manually set your report parameter labels and values as follows

[image]

Then in you data query just do something like

```
SELECT * 
    FROM myTable t 
    WHERE 
           (@myParam = 1 AND NoOfRecords BETWEEN 1 AND 2)
        OR (@myParam = 2 AND NoOfRecords BETWEEN 3 AND 4)
        OR (@myParam = 3 AND NoOfRecords >= 5)
```

Make sure `myParam` is the name of your SSRS report parameter, it is case sensitive.

Comment: Glad to help. If this answered your question, could you please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark to the left of the answer, under the vote up/down buttons). This helps others find answered questions. Thanks